# How can I change the default border color and default heigth for checkboxes for ContactForm7 for WordPress with CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm kinda new to `CSS` and the `Contact Form 7 Plugin` for `WordPress`, but somehow I can't change the color and the height of the checkbox borders. For the textboxes it worked already perfectly. But the checkboxes are my problem now. As you can see on the pic I´d like to change the bordercolor to white and also set the text perfectly behind the checkbox.

The `CSS` code I used so far:

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-acceptance label {
display: flex;
line-height: flex;}

.wpcf7-form span.ZustimmungDatenschutz { float: left; margin-right: 05px;}
.wpcf7-form span.ZustimmungDatenschutz input[type=checkbox] { margin: 0; }
.wpcf7-form span.ZustimmungDatenschutz input[type=checkbox] { width: 0px; height: middle px; margin: 0; }
```

Example of my problem:-

[image: Example of my problem]

Comment: Welcome to CSS! It's a very good question, and unfortunately there's not a straight-forward answer. Please check out this answer here where it has been very well researched. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Comment: Hey @neatlysliced, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the answer to the question isn't really helping me, as I tried the solutions written there.. As it seems the border is set in the "span" (class?). But due to my lack of knowledge, I can't overwrite the color of the border in the "span" to change it to "white" or unvisible. So I need `CSS` to overwrite the "span" and then change the color to unvisible. And the size of the border should be also 3 rows like the text. 

Hopefully someone can help me. I'm not fully happy with the solution by now.

Comment: there are a lot of links on there. Did you see the 2021 answer? It links to a JSFiddle. If you edit the border in the CSS for it (grey in the example), it should work as you are hoping. The HTML needs to match as well. If you are unable to control the HTML output, you may need to use JavaScript to accomplish this. http://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/2cs0dj54/